# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Model' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a CRUD app, everything works except updating tags

Here is the `update` function in my controller

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Tag;
use App\PageList;
use App\PageListTag;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $pages = PageList::find($id);
    $pages->pagetitle =  $request->get('pagetitle');
    $pages->articlelist = $request->get('articlelist');
    $pages->status = $request->get('status');

    $pages->save();

    $pages->tags()->saveMany([
        new App\Tag(),
        new App\Tag(),
    ]);

    return redirect('/pages')->with('success', 'pages updated!');
}
```

Here is the `Tag` model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['page_list_id', 'page_list_tag_id'];

    protected $with = ['tag'];

    public function tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PageListTag', 'page_list_tag_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

When I run my app I am getting the following error

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Tag' not found

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're resolving in the wrong way the models namespaces. Please have a look at the official [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php)

In your code you're resolving the `Tag` class as follows

```
use App\Tag; // <-- This is right
```

But in your method you're calling

```
$pages->tags()->saveMany([
    new App\Tag(), // <-- And this is wrong!
    new App\Tag(),
]);
```

You simply have to call `new Tag()` since the `use` at the top of your file has already included the class.

Otherwise PHP will try to resolve the class from the current namespace. That's why it's throwing

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Tag' not found
```

To be right you should have added a `\` before `App\Tag`, so PHP will resolve the class from the root. In this case, the `use` statement will be useless

Comment: Your right , is there any best method to save my tags instead of what am doing ?, now I am getting this error : Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: This error is not related to your question. You're trying somewhere else to retrive an attribute from a non-object (so maybe it's a null value returned by a query that can't find a model in your database). If you think that my answer is the right one, please accept it. For the other problem please ask another question, we'll be glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

Your namespace is `App\Http\Controllers`, so when you create a tag with the syntax `new App\Tag()` it is indeed translated into `App\Http\Controllers\App\Tag`.

So just replace your instructions `new App\Tag()` with `new Tag()`.

Alternatively, you could also use the absolute notation:

```
new \App\Tag()
```